# Why does floated div overlap the next element?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div  id="tabs">
      ertgertget
    </div>

    <div id="design">
       EHELLOW RODL
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#design{
    border: solid 10px black;
}

#tabs {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2NLK8/

Why does the second div not *completely appear to the right of* the floated div?

Comment: im not exactly sure what you want to achieve.. what about this: http://jsfiddle.net/omegaiori/2NLK8/2/

Comment: Another good solution. But why is it necessary?

Comment: i can't understand what you need man :)

Comment: I need what your solution provides. I don't understand why the divs overlap in the original.

Comment: because you had just ONE floated element. if you want a div next to the other you have to use float on both elements

Comment: Think this is it... http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#img-float2p

Answer (score 1):

```
#design{
   border: solid 10px black;
   overflow:auto;
 }

#tabs {
   border: 1px solid red;
   float: left;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2NLK8/7/)

Comment: Yes great. You don't need the width in your version.

Comment: Why does it need the overflow property set?

Comment: You've provided a solution but not an explanation of the original conundrum.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#design {
    border: solid 10px black;
    display:inline;
}

#tabs {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display:inline;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2NLK8/6/)

Comment: Yes like that. But why doesn't it do it with the original version?

Comment: And you don't need the float in your version.

Answer (score 0):

Because the floated element, take as much space as it content, while a default block element will take an entire row. If you want your second div to be aligned to the right, float it right

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2NLK8/3/ If I fix the width it still appears under the floated div. So it doesn't need an entire row.

Answer (score 0):

I would get yourself familiar with "clearfix".

Check it out here: [Force Element To Self-Clear its Children](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

It will "clear" floats in these types of cases. It's a very commonly used method in the industry.